# Object ArrayList within Object ArrayList extended by class java

Tags: java, class, variables, object, arraylist

I have created a class with a group of objects which contain strings and booleans named "*Accessories*"

then created ArrayList class which is then added to the list named "*AccessoriesList*", from there more data is inputted.

I then created an Accessories object to receive to data from the ArrayList, using a for loop. this still responses as null.

I have looked around and found that the most common problem is that the variables have not been initialized. So i tried and still getting the same result

so here is the *accessories* class

```
    public static class Accessories {

    Accessories(String Accessoriesname, boolean cold, boolean warm, boolean hot, boolean rain, boolean snow, boolean ice, boolean formal, boolean informal) {
    }
    String name =null ; boolean cold; boolean warm; boolean hot; boolean rain; boolean snow; boolean ice; boolean formal; boolean informal;
}
```

Here is the *AccessoriesList* class

```
 public ArrayList createAccessories() {
    ArrayList<Accessories> Accessoriesist = new ArrayList<Accessories>();
    Accessoriesist.add(new Accessories("Bag", true, true, true, false, false, false, true, true));
    Accessoriesist.add(new Accessories("Gloves", true, false, false, true, true, true, true, true));
    Accessoriesist.add(new Accessories("Hat", true, false, false, true, true, true, false, true));
    Accessoriesist.add(new Accessories("Poncho", false, true, true, false, false, false, false, true));
    Accessoriesist.add(new Accessories("Scarf", true, true, false, true, true, true, true, true));
    Accessoriesist.add(new Accessories("Sunglasses", false, true, true, false, false, false, true, true));
    Accessoriesist.add(new Accessories("Tie", true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true));

    Accessories getAccessories =null;
    String getname = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < Accessoriesist.size(); i++) {
        getAccessories =  Accessoriesist.get(i);
        getname = getAccessories.name;
        System.out.println("this is the name : " + getname);
        System.out.println("this is the Accessoriesist : " + Accessoriesist.get(i));
    }
    return Accessoriesist;
}
```

Instead of receiving the information, I receive the hash-code.

I am trying to throw an Accessories Object(orginal) from an ArrayList, into another Accessories Object(new). i am trying to pull the data from the Accessories Object(new)

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

First, your constructor never copies the properties you pass to it into the class:
    Accessories(String Accessoriesname, boolean cold, boolean warm, boolean hot, boolean rain, boolean snow, boolean ice, boolean formal, boolean informal) {
    }

Think of a constructor as a method call with variable parameters: in this case you do nothing between your curly braces `{` and `}`. Java provides you with the `this` keyword to refer to a property of the class instance. So you need to explicitly copy the *parameters* passed to your constructor to the *properties* of your class instance:

```
Accessories(String Accessories name, boolean cold, boolean warm, boolean hot, boolean rain, boolean snow, boolean ice, boolean formal, boolean informal) {
    this.name = name
    this.cold = cold
    this.warm = warm
    this.hot = hot
    this.rain = rain
    this.snow = snow
    this.ice = ice
    this.formal = formal
    this.informal = informal
}
```

Second, because this line of code is concatenating a String with an object, it will call the .toString() method on your Accessories object:

```
    System.out.println("this is the Accessoriesist : " + Accessoriesist.get(i));
```

The default implementation of the `.toString()` method is inherited from the Object superclass. If you'd like to override it, just add a method to your class with the same method signature as `Object.toString()`

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(this.name);
    if (ice) {
        sb.append(" (ice)")
    }
    // other properties
    return sb.toString()
}
```

A few final notes:

- It is conventional in Java to use CamelCase. For classes, we use a
  capital letter for the first letter (MyClass) and for class member
  variables and parameters we use a lowercase letter for the first
  letter (myClass). So your `ArrayList<Accessories> Accessoriesist`
  would be `ArrayList<Accessories> accessoriesList` following this
  convention.
- It might be a good idea to make all of your different
  properties (cold, warm, ice, snow, etc) an `enum` called something
  like `Properties` and to have your Accessories class contain a
  List.

Welcome to Java!